# Comparing all column names of multiple Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am looking for an easier way to compare multiple column names with a similar output to the code below or a way to make this function more concise. I get the errors "IndexError: list index out of range" or "function takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" every time I try to use *args or **Kwargs to simplify the function. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

'''

```
application_df = pd.read_csv("application_train.csv")
bureau_df = pd.read_csv("bureau.csv")
bureau_balance_df = pd.read_csv("bureau_balance.csv")
previous_application_df = pd.read_csv("previous_application.csv")
POS_CASH_balance_df = pd.read_csv("POS_CASH_balance.csv")
installments_payments_df = pd.read_csv("installments_payments.csv")
credit_card_balance_df = pd.read_csv("credit_card_balance.csv")
sample__submission_df = pd.read_csv("sample_submission.csv")

def column_compare(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8):
    alist = []
    blist = []
    clist = []
    dlist = []
    elist = []
    flist = []
    glist = []
    hlist = []
    
    name1 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df1][0]
    for a in df1:
        alist.append(a)
        
    name2 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df2][0]
    for b in df2:
        blist.append(b)
        
    name3 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df3][0]
    for c in df3:
        clist.append(c)
        
    name4 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df4][0]
    for d in df4:
        dlist.append(d)
        
    name5 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df5][0]
    for e in df5:
        elist.append(e)
        
    name6 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df6][0]
    for f in df6:
        flist.append(f)
        
    name7 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df7][0]
    for g in df7:
        glist.append(g)
        
    name8 =[x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df8][0]
    for h in df8:
        hlist.append(h)
        
    dfs = {name1: alist, name2: blist, name3: clist, name4: dlist, name5: elist, name6: flist, name7: glist, name8: hlist}
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfs, orient='index')
    df=df.transpose().replace(np.nan,'')
    return df

pd.set_option("max_rows", None)
column_names = column_compare(application_df, bureau_df, bureau_balance_df, previous_application_df, POS_CASH_balance_df, installments_payments_df, credit_card_balance_df, sample__submission_df)
column_names
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are interested in, but column names can be access through `df.columns`, so:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abc'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abefg'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('bfkm'))

cols1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.columns).assign(df1=1).T
cols2 = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.columns).assign(df2=1).T
cols3 = pd.DataFrame(index=df3.columns).assign(df3=1).T

df_cols_compare = pd.concat([cols1, cols2, cols3]).fillna(0).astype('int')

#      a  b  c  e  f  g  k  m
# df1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0
# df2  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0
# df3  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  1
```